# re-size Jpanel dynamically when different value selected in combo box

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-platform, swingx

I have a issue in the Panel alignment. My project is in Netbeans Platform Application, so by default window will be created. Below is what i have done:

- I have created a window and when i select a string, a button will be enabled and clicking on that button a pop-up window appears.
- The popup id divided into 3 panels:

  ```
        ---> 1 st - with a labels and text box
        ---> 2nd - with a card layout where the layout changes based upon the combo box selection from the first panel.
        ---> 3rd panel - here i have 2 buttons.
  ```
- Now i want the buttons to get adjusted when i cardlayout size decreases and increases. Eg: when the size of the card layout is more it go down if less it should come up.

i have tried the Auto Vertical re-sizable option in Netbeans but it isn't working properly.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: BTW - what does this have to do with your IDE, the desktop app. framework that is associated with it, or swingx?

Comment: @raj  See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Add - `setSize` to the comment as well (yes it should be avoided)

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Huh.. it had completely slipped by my attention that that title does not explicitly cover `setSize(..)`. But yes, agreed, it should also be avoided (as I thought was my point, before you corrected my perception).

Comment: @AndrewThompson No issue with comment(s) ;)